# How can I use an acf_form() submission to also update my post title and permalink?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, permalinks, acfpro

I have a WordPress site and I am using acf_form() to allow users to update ACF fields of a custom post type (this part is working fine). But I also want the post title and permalink to change based on a particular ACF field. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I went down a route that no longer makes this necessary to do, so I will close the question.

Comment: Guess I can't close it for some reason, so it'll stay open. Maybe it can help somebody else.